# How to use latex in the csv file produced by python

Tags: python, csv, latex

I want to use latex interpreter in the csv file produced by python. I want to use some special character as gamma in subscript and superscript.

In the example below I tried to use Unicode to print text in the csv file named Output.csv. The quality was pretty low and some letters are missing, e.g., subscript of letter W.

```
import csv
gamma_G=[1 ,1.3] 
gamma_Q=[0 ,1.2] 

Line_1 = [['2', gamma_G[1] , 'G \u2096' ,  gamma_Q[1], '0', 'Q \u0077,\u2096,\u2081' ,'0','0', '0']]

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvFile:

    thewriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',') 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=["INPUT" ])
    writer.writeheader()
    thewriter.writerows(Line_1)
```

The expected result is to have an high quolity text with Greek letters printed in the csv file.

Is there an encoding library compatible with .csv that allows for special characters, sub and super script characters with the range of Latex?

Comment: How and when do you expect the LATEX markup to be rendered?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. If you run my code, you can see that the output is a couple of lines. I know how to use latex in matlab and it is really easy to apply in charts. You just have to specify the interpreter. I would like to define the interpreter latex in python in order to have nice greek symbol in the csv file.

Comment: And what should this "nice greek symbols" be in a text based file? Unicode? A graphic? Something else? How do expect the process of having LATEX code in a CSV file to seeing the rendered output in a program (like a spreadsheet application) that opens the CSV file to work technically?

Comment: Are you trying to "auto-generate" latex code that compiles? Then the "csv" might be a bit misleading. You could generate ascii (text) files that can be incluced in Latex.

Comment: Hi, I believe there are some misanderstandings. Let s try to make it easier. I want to print in the csv file the letter W in capitol positioned in the subscript. How to do that? In case you used Unicode, the letter W in capitol positioned a subscript do not exist. You have to use the letter VV . I believe thare should be a way to plot any letter, symbol... by calling the interpreter in latex in python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck...

If you are wondering why there is a limitation in the UTF-8 encoding for subscripts and superscripts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

.csv files don't support encoding that allow sub and superscript for all characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Latex is a markup language not an encoding library.